# How to get generic type inference with strictNullChecks to match on less restrictive type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a generic function that takes two arguments, one of which is a sum of a type variable, null, and undefined, the other is just the type variable. Typescript is infering the type variable from the second argument.

I already know ways to annotate around this - explicitly setting the type variable with `<>` or a type assertion on the second argument.

I am considering digging into conditional types to see if they can filter out the, it's not clear to me that they can.

```
const or = <T>(x: T|null|undefined, y:T): T =>
    x === null || x === undefined ? y : x;

const test: Map<string,number> = new Map();
const result = or(test.get('test'), 0);
```

I'd like it to typecheck, and `result` should have type `number` - instead I get "Type 'number' is not assignable to type '0 | null | undefined'.".

Likewise with a list of somethings and an empty list, I get that the somethings are not assignable to `never`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I got it.

```
const or = <T, S extends T>(x: T|null|undefined, y:S>: T =>
    x === null || x == undefined ? y : x;
```

I started out with a slightly more complicated thing with conditional types, and then realized I could move that assumption into an additional type paramater.